# How to convert alpha numerical and special characters string to alphabetical string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdstring, std

In a function, a string is passed which has alphabets, numbers and special characters. The function should return only the alphabets from the string.

I tried the following code but it is giving along with the numbers as well. Where am I going wrong?

In this code (using c++11) `std::string::find_first_not_of` stl algorithm is being used

```
 std::string jobName1 = "job_2";

 std::size_t found = 
  jobName1.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJK
  LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
 while (found!=std::string::npos)
 {
    jobName1.erase(found,1);
    found=jobName1.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAB
    CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",(found+1));
 }
```

Input:

```
job_2
```

Output:

```
job2
```

Expected:

```
job
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You have an off by one error.  `find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAB
    CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",(found+1))` should be `find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAB
    CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",(found))` since you erased `found` so `found + 1` is the next, next character as `found` is now the next character.

Comment: @NathanOliver Great ... Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: @Sagar Next time, use [std::remove_if](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/149d9dd4949e6d81).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, this is should do the job:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string jobName1 = "job_2";
  std::regex regex ("[0-9_]*");

  auto result = std::regex_replace (jobName1, regex, "");
  std::cout << result << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something other than the code you've written, you can use [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <cctype>

 int main()
 {
     std::string jobName1 = "job_2";
     jobName1.erase(std::remove_if(jobName1.begin(), jobName1.end(),
                                  [](char ch){return !std::isalpha(ch);}),
                                  jobName1.end());
     std::cout << jobName1;
 }
```

Output:

```
job
```

Comment: isn't it much efficient to create a new string out from the existing, for all character inside it `std::isalpha`? something like: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ve1si4N4jlMNjSkc

Comment: @JeJo -- Well, I propose you post an answer using `std::copy_if`, which is basically what your code is doing.  I'll give credit if you do that :-)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to already given `std::string::find_first_not_of`, `std::regex_replace`, `std::remove_if` solutions, [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) can be used to copy the charectors of given string to new one, if it [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).(credits to *@PaulMcKenzie* for poting the right algorithum)

**([See Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tnCi814iYzKrNSVo))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // std::copy_if
#include <iterator>  // std::back_inserter 
#include <cctype>    // std::isalpha

int main()
{
    const std::string jobName1{ "job_2" };
    std::string result;
    std::copy_if(std::cbegin(jobName1), std::cend(jobName1),
        std::back_inserter(result),
        [](const char chr) noexcept { return std::isalpha(chr); });
    std::cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
job
```